# Error when refresh snap package

Tags: 20.04, snap, ubuntu-core, telegram

When refreshing telegram-desktop manually with `sudo snap refresh telegram-desktop`. The following error appears:

```
Copy snap "telegram-desktop" data

2021-03-25T12:31:17+07:00 ERROR cannot copy "/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448" to "/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551": failed to copy all: "'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448' -> '/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551'\n'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448/.themes' -> '/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551/.themes'\n'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448/.config' -> '/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551/.config'\n'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448/.config/mimeapps.list' -> '/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551/.config/mimeapps.list'\n'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448/.config/user-dirs.dirs' -> '/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551/.config/user-dirs.dirs'\n'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448/.config/user-dirs.dirs.md5sum' -> '/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551/.config/user-dirs.dirs.md5sum'\n'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448/.config/user-dirs.locale' -> '/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2551/.config/user-dirs.locale'\n'/home/nawan/snap/telegram-desktop/2448/.config/user-dirs.locale.md5sum'
```

Honestly, i'm not familiar with snap package manager.

This is what appears when I type `snap changes`:

`77   Error   today at 05:28 UTC      today at 05:32 UTC      Refresh snap "telegram-desktop"`

For more information, here details of the snap version, operating system, and kernel version the obtained from `snap version`:

```
snap    2.49.1
snapd   2.49.1
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.4.0-70-generic
```

Comment: The system cannot copy files in your home folder. Do you have free space left? What happens if you omit the `sudo` before the command? If you are not familiar with snap package manager, why the need to manually refresh?